# Pairwise correlation from Dunnett's rank test

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to represent the Dunnett's test results in a heatmap, highlighting the correlations between groups.

Output:

```
                           mean.rank.diff    pval    
EpisodeFourL-EpisodeFiveL      -51.418401 0.33175    
EpisodeOneL-EpisodeFiveL        38.505311 1.00000    
EpisodeSixL-EpisodeFiveL        34.267816 1.00000    
EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeFiveL     -68.548095 0.07237 .  
EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeFiveL       -93.324843 0.00504 ** 
EpisodeOneL-EpisodeFourL        89.923712 0.03094 *  
EpisodeSixL-EpisodeFourL        85.686217 0.12094    
EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeFourL     -17.129694 1.00000    
EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeFourL       -41.906442 0.60473    
EpisodeSixL-EpisodeOneL         -4.237495 1.00000    
EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeOneL     -107.053407 0.00484 ** 
EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeOneL       -131.830154 0.00024 ***
EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeSixL     -102.815911 0.03506 *  
EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeSixL       -127.592659 0.00484 ** 
EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeThreeL      -24.776748 1.00000
```

How can I make a "correlation matrix of p values", so that it will look like the following, with the cells recording `the mean rank diff` coloured by the `p-values?`

Thanks for your time

[image]

I am struggling with the following steps:

1. pairwise comparison - how to arrange my data to have on the 2 axes the episode names;
2. how to split the episodes into 2 groups M and L;
3. how to create a correlation heatmaps with `mean rank diff` values in the cells and `p-values` used to coloured the cells

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(mean.rank.diff = c(31.793661, 50.78439, -93.432344, 
-61.09784, -30.52092, -43.07989, 26.230952, 65.94858, 11.569245, 
20.41009, -125.226005, -111.88223, -62.31458, -93.86428, -5.562709, 
15.16419, -20.224416, -30.3743, 62.911425, 18.01795, 119.663297, 
127.04642, 105.00159, 81.50793, 56.751872, 109.02847, 42.090165, 
63.48998, -14.661707, -45.53849), pval = c(1, 0.43984, 0.03031, 
0.37802, 1, 1, 1, 0.1446, 1, 1, 0.00049, 0.00207, 0.85499, 0.10108, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.00098, 0.00033, 0.00782, 0.09761, 1, 0.03568, 
1, 0.60994, 1, 0.60994)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("EpisodeFourL-EpisodeFiveL", 
"EpisodeFourM-EpisodeFiveM", "EpisodeOneL-EpisodeFiveL", "EpisodeOneM-EpisodeFiveM", 
"EpisodeSixL-EpisodeFiveL", "EpisodeSixM-EpisodeFiveM", "EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeFiveL", 
"EpisodeThreeM-EpisodeFiveM", "EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeFiveL", "EpisodeTwoM-EpisodeFiveM", 
"EpisodeOneL-EpisodeFourL", "EpisodeOneM-EpisodeFourM", "EpisodeSixL-EpisodeFourL", 
"EpisodeSixM-EpisodeFourM", "EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeFourL", "EpisodeThreeM-EpisodeFourM", 
"EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeFourL", "EpisodeTwoM-EpisodeFourM", "EpisodeSixL-EpisodeOneL", 
"EpisodeSixM-EpisodeOneM", "EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeOneL", "EpisodeThreeM-EpisodeOneM", 
"EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeOneL", "EpisodeTwoM-EpisodeOneM", "EpisodeThreeL-EpisodeSixL", 
"EpisodeThreeM-EpisodeSixM", "EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeSixL", "EpisodeTwoM-EpisodeSixM", 
"EpisodeTwoL-EpisodeThreeL", "EpisodeTwoM-EpisodeThreeM"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

1. Making use of `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr` you can split your rownames into episodes and groups
2. After the data wrangling you can get a heatmap via `geom_tile`, `geom_text` and `facet_grid`
3. Finally, I made some adjustments to put the facet labels outside and to put the x-axis on the top.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

levels <- paste0("Episode", c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"))
labels <- paste("Episode", c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"))
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(episodes = row.names(.)) %>% 
  separate(episodes, into = c("episode1", "episode2")) %>% 
  mutate(type1 = stringr::str_extract(episode1, ".$"), 
         type2 = stringr::str_extract(episode1, ".$"),
         across(c(episode1, episode2), ~ stringr::str_remove(., ".$")),
         across(c(episode1, episode2), ~ factor(., levels = levels, labels = labels)),
         across(c(type1, type2), ~ factor(., levels = c("M", "L"))))

ggplot(df1, aes(type1, forcats::fct_rev(type2), fill = pval)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(mean.rank.diff, accuracy = .1))) +
  facet_grid(episode1 ~ episode2, switch = "y") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]